# Why won't the search bar hide on the iPhone 6 Plus?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, uisearchbar

I have a a table view with a search bar controller/search bar as the header which I want to hide when the view loads. I have the following code in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(indexesInRange: NSMakeRange(0, self.tableView.numberOfSections())), withRowAnimation: .None)
```

This works perfectly on the iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 simulators but for some reason does not work at all for the iPhone 6 Plus. Is this just a bug in said device simulator or bad practice on my part?

Thanks!